# Escape Latin-1 ( ISO-8859-1) to utf-8 String in Java

Tags: java, json, escaping, iso-8859-1

I tried to use [Gson](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide)  and [org.json](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json) as the examples. I tried [Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) as well, but I doesn't work for me, when I import the library manually (I not allowed to use Maven). So I decided to search for another solution.

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils

I need to escape an Array to Json this way. Especially `Ó`, `ó` or any Latin-1 character( Not escape `"`, just escape what is in `"&%$/"Helló"` ). Original message: `Helló / // \ "WÓRLD"`

```
{"token":"045-245","message":"Helló / // \\ \"WÓRLD\" "}
```

to

```
{"token":"045-245","message":"Hell\u00F3 / // \\ \"W\u00D3RLD\" "}
```

This what I get when I use:

Gson

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("token", "045-245");
json.addProperty("message", "Helló WÓRLD");
String payload = new Gson().toJson(json);
System.out.println(payload);
```

Result:

```
{"token":"045-245","message":"Helló WÓRLD"}
```

org.json

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();        
jsonObject.put("token", "045-245");
jsonObject.put("message", "Helló WÓRLD");
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

Result:

```
{"message":"Helló WÓRLD","token":"045-245"}
```

Comment: Gson does not support this (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091804/gson-unicode-characters-conversion-to-unicode-character-codes for a workaround). But Jackson does! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121765/write-objectnode-to-json-string-with-utf-8-characters-to-escaped-ascii

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write ObjectNode to JSON String with UTF-8 Characters to Escaped ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121765/write-objectnode-to-json-string-with-utf-8-characters-to-escaped-ascii)

Comment: @dnault Thanks, but do need I to use Maven ? I donwloaded the last Jackson version, but Netbeans can't manage `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()`. Because as I ask, I am not allowed to use Maven.

Comment: You just need to have Jackson on your classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dnault I found Jackson Json Library. I needed to import `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`, `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`. I imported  `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotations` as well, for no problems on JDK 8.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class Foo {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.getFactory().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
    ObjectNode node = mapper.getNodeFactory().objectNode();
    node.put("token", "045-245");
    node.put("message", "Helló / // \\ \"WÓRLD\" ");
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(node));

}
```

Output:

```
{"token":"045-245","message":"Hell\u00F3 / // \\ \"W\u00D3RLD\" "}
```