# unicode characters in json file to be unconverted after managing java gson

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to manage a json file with gson in java; the file contains sone unicode characters, and I don't want to convert them; the structure tree of json file after my changes must be the same of original.

The **file.json**:

```
{"name":"\u300AMWXT\u300B - xL","olsa":"","pose":"\u300ATHE\u300BP97UL","resa":"33.0","utrk":"101351",...}
```

I've tried with this code:

```
FileReader filer = new FileReader(".\\file.json"); 
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(filer);
String content;
try {
    content = file.readLine();
    file.close();
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(content, JsonElement.class); 
    JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject(); 
    int utrk = jsonObj.get("utrk").getAsInt();
    utrk = utrk + (215);
    jsonObj.addProperty("utrk", utrk); 
...}
```

All works correctly, but in the `JsonElement` element `name` become `《MWXT》 - xL` and `pose` do the same, and so the result is not how I would like to be.
Any suggestion?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091804) but the answer not solve original question two years ago and I think that in two years many changes can be made...

Comment: I've tested your code by printing the whole decoded JSON object to stdout on a UTF8 configured console. It prints `{"name":"《MWXT》 - xL","olsa":"","pose":"《THE》P97UL","resa":"33.0","utrk":"101351"}` which I assume is correct.

Comment: Please detail how you're inspecting the decoded output. Also, your code does not include any reference to writing the output to `filedest.json`

Comment: You hit my problem:  {"name":"《MWXT》 - xL","olsa":"","pose":"《THE》P97UL","resa":"33.0","utrk":"101351"}    must remain {"name":"\u300AMWXT\u300B - xL","olsa":"","pose":"\u300ATHE\u300BP97UL","resa":"33.0","utrk":"101351",...}

Comment: I think is not important to include how I write the output to filedest.json. My problem is in the line code: `JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(content, JsonElement.class);`: here "name":"\u300AMWXT\u300B - xL" became "name":"《MWXT》 - xL", and I don't want it, I want no change

Comment: Only to let know which is my goal, but the problem, how you see, is previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, big advantage of unicode characters is that any client reads and treats the code "\u..." just the same as its character representation. For instance if in html file if you replace every single character with its unicode representation the browser will read it as usual. I.e. replace 'H' in "Hello world" with '\u0048' (which is unicode for 'H') and in the browser you will still see "Hello world". But in this case it works against you as Gson simply replaces unicodes with their symbols.

My suggestion may not be perfect but it will work. Before converting your Object remember the location of your unicode symbols and after conversion change them back to unicodes. Here is the tool that may help you: There is an open source library MgntUtils (written by me) that has a utility that converts any string to sequence of unicodes and vise-versa.

You can do:

```
String s = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello world");
```

And it will give you String: `"\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064"` and then you can do this:

```
    String s 
= StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString("\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064");
```

And it will return you String "Hello world".  It works with any language. Here is the link to the article that explains where to get the library: [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman) Look for paragraph titled "**String Unicode converter**"

Here is the link to Maven artifacts: [MgntUtils maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and here is a link to [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) with sources and javadoc included.Here is [javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)